# OnRowCommand event sometimes not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have GridView with ButtonField:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="activitygrid" runat="server" CssClass="EU_DataTable" class="ui-body-d"   OnRowCommand="activitygrid_RowCommand1"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="activitygrid_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" >


      <asp:ButtonField CommandName="cmdRegister" Text="register now"  ControlStyle-CssClass="table-stripe" HeaderText="register" ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-Height="20px" >
                         <ControlStyle CssClass="table-stripe"></ControlStyle>
                     </asp:ButtonField>
```

page load code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                     
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    BindData();
                }

                else
                {

                    BindDataSecondTime();
                }            
        }
```

RowCommand code:

```
protected void activitygrid_RowCommand1(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);


            if (e.CommandName == "cmdRegister")
            {
                registerActivities.Add(relActivities[index]);

                //Update the sum
                CurrentSum += relActivities[index].ActivityPrice;
                lblSum.Text = CurrentSum.ToString();

                selectedactivitygrid.DataSource = registerActivities;
                selectedactivitygrid.DataBind();

                relActivities.Remove(relActivities[index]);

                activitygrid.DataSource = relActivities;
                activitygrid.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

The problem is when i click on the button sometimes the event firing (usually when I click in the middle of the button) and sometimes not .

Please help.

Comment: show the code page too. specially the page_load and OnRowCommand

Comment: Which browser are you testing this? Does all browsers(IE/FF/Chrome) exhibit the same behavior? Though silly but what If you remove the style temporarily and give it a try?

Comment: I tested it in ie and chrome and the behavior was same, and I tried to remove the style but it not but it had no effect.

Comment: Are you using any update panels on the page? You may want to show the html around the gridview as well in case something else is causing the issue.

Comment: add a breakpoint and see if it hits on every row command

Answer (score 0):

I remove `ControlStyle-Height="20px"` and its worked out.